# Does changing the position of "when" change the meaning？

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

Does changing the position of **when** change the sentence meaning？

> 1. I broke my leg when I was playing football.
> 2. I was playing football when I broke my leg.

Is there any difference in these two sentences? Which one makes more sense in terms of meaning?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the meaning is the same. Your choice is a matter of what is sometimes called "information packaging."

Whenever possible, native speakers place new information toward the end of a clause or a sentence. The opposite is also true: we tend to put familiar or given information at or near the beginning of a clause or a sentence.

In #1, the speaker is making the assumption that the audience is familiar with the **broken leg**—perhaps because the cast is evident, perhaps because they have been discussing it recently. WHEN the speaker broke the leg—**when I was playing football**—is "the news," the point of the sentence.

In #2, **I broke my leg** is the news. Presumably, the audience is familiar with the speaker's habit of **playing football**—or at least familiar with the sport and the fact that people like the speaker play it.

Source: *Style: Lessons in Clarity and Grace* by Williams and Bizup.

It's worth noting that in speech, any of what I have just described can be altered if the speaker emphasizes another part of the sentence by means of intonation. Imagine the following:

> I broke MY LEG when I was playing football. *[I did not break my arm.]*
> I BROKE my leg when I was playing football. *[I did not sprain my leg.]*

Comment: My intuition is that #1 gives an emphasis on the fact that 'I broke my leg', and that one might use it when he/she comes home limping and is asked what happened to him/her. #2 emphasizes what the speaker was doing when the bad luck occurred, so it might be used in a situation like being asked by a police officer about the activity one was engaged in when something occurred.